# How can I set the request IP in a Capybara feature spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am using RSpec and Capybara for my feature specs on my Rails 5.1 app. I want to fake the request IP to '1.2.3.4' for a single spec.

I've tried the following with Poltergeist...

```
before do
  page.driver.add_headers 'REMOTE_HOST' => '1.2.3.4'
end
```

However, placing a pry in my controller I see that `request.headers['REMOTE_HOST']` is `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Sounds like this is more applicable to a controller spec or request spec than a feature spec.

Comment: I want to test different behavior in my views based on the request IP

Comment: That can be done from a view spec or request spec or controller spec (if you tell it to render the views).  All places you could modify the request, and/or where its normal to mock/stub things (unlike feature tests)

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by stubbing `ActionDispatch::Request#remote_ip`

```
allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:remote_ip) { '1.2.3.4' }
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object

I would prefer altering the actual request if possible.