# Setting the request host for one specific example in rspec system test using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Capybara's request.host is `"www.example.com"`, but I want to change it to `"www.example.2.com"` for just one specific test in a system rspec.

```
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5.0'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 3.6.0'
```

```
scenario "asdf user see asdf page" do

    create_asdf

    !host 'example.2.com'

    visit root_path
    
    expect(page).to have_css("#asdf")

  end
```

This fails, as does all variations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Capybara and Selenium in conjunction with RSpec to conduct Web Interface testing, and the setup is functioning effectively. However, for a particular integration test, I required a callback on `localhost:3000/auth/*`. By default, Capybara initiates tests on an unusual host and port combination to prevent conflicts with `localhost:3000`, which is the default host and port for Rails Apps in development. It took me around 30 minutes to figure out how to enforce Capybara to run all tests on `localhost:3000`. I believe this information is valuable enough to share through a blog post

You can make these configurations either in your `spec_helper.rb` or in `spec/support/capybara.rb`:

```rb
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/firebug'
```

After importing the necessary modules, proceed to configure Capybara as follows:

```rb
Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"
Capybara.server_host = "localhost"
Capybara.server_port = "3000"
```

With these settings, all tests executed by Capybara will run on `localhost:3000`. This allows for successful testing of the required integration scenario involving the callback. By documenting this setup, I hope it proves helpful to others who encounter similar challenges when working with Capybara and Selenium.